# why dataflow is not supported by self hosted IR

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I know as per Azure documentation DataFlow is only allowed in AutoResolve IR (Azure IR), but looking for reason why is it not allowed in Self Hosted IR.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data flows requires a Spark environment, which the Azure IR provides. That serverless Spark environment is not provided by self-hosted IR. However, you can achieve the same things in Azure IR as you can in self-hosted IR in terms of accessing data in a vnet and on-prem.

Comment: I don't have the option to upvote but yeah that's correct.
ARIR on backend converts the DF to Databricks job which  currently is only supported by ARIR. https://www.avaus.com/blog/azure-data-flow-etl-in-the-cloud/